# Python - Job Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, job-scheduling

I'm working on a python class that generates a schedule. I created a mockup of the class that I have in mind and examples of creating objects to interface with it.

```
class JobScheduler(object):
    def __init__(self, start_time: int, stop_time: int):
        self.start_time
        self.stop_time

    def add_job(self, job_type, job_config, interval, duration, resource, prevent_resource_overlap=True):
        pass

    def generate_schedule(self):
        pass

job_scheduler = JobScheduler(start_time=0, stop_time=3600)

job_scheduler.add_job(
    job_type='CLEAN_ROOM', 
    job_config={'args': 'xyz'},
    interval=32,
    duration=30,
    resource='VACUUM')

job_scheduler.add_job(
    job_type='CLEAN_KITCHEN', 
    job_config={'args': 'xyz'},
    interval=300,
    duration=30,
    resource='VACUUM')

job_scheduler.add_job(
    job_type='CLEAN_ROOM', 
    job_config={'args': 'xyz'},
    interval=300,
    duration=30,
    resource='MOP')

job_scheduler.add_job(
    job_type='CLEAN_ROOM', 
    job_config={'args': 'xyz'},
    interval=100,
    duration=30,
    resource='VACUUM',
    prevent_resource_overlap=False)

job_scheduler.generate_schedule()

[
    {
        "job_type": "CLEAN_ROOM",
        "job_config": {'args': 'xyz'},
        "start_time": 0,
        "duration": 30,
        "resource": "VACUUM"
    },
    {
        "job_type": "CLEAN_ROOM",
        "job_config": {'args': 'xyz'},
        "start_time": 0,
        "duration": 30,
        "resource": "MOP"
    },
    {
        "job_type": "CLEAN_ROOM",
        "job_config": {'args': 'xyz'},
        "start_time": 0,
        "duration": 30,
        "resource": "VACUUM"
    },
    {
        "job_type": "CLEAN_KITCHEN",
        "job_config": {'args': 'xyz'},
        "start_time": 32,
        "duration": 30,
        "resource": "VACUUM"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

The tricky part is that the schedule should prevent other jobs that use the same `resource` from overlapping unless `prevent_resource_overlap=False`. We also need to round-robin these overlapping resources so they eventually get scheduled. For job's where `prevent_resource_overlap=True`, we're allowed exceed the interval if needed for the scheduling frequency.

Any tips on how to do this efficiently?

Comment: Your question "Any tips on how to do this efficiently?" is too vague i.m.o.  You seem to be on the right track but didn't finish the code. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "efficiently".  Memory? Computation speed? Code simplicity?  Code elegance?

Comment: I recommend finishing what you want to do one way, and then asking a specific question such as "is there another way to do this that is <better in some way>"? For example, since you are using datetimes, you could start with an implementation using a pandas Series. Make sure the code example runs and then we can look at it and think if there is a better way.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into pandas Series. In my mind, I was thinking about initializing a dict where the key is the "resource" and the value is an array containing None for the length (num of second) for stop_time - start_time. 
I'll have the code find an open spot and replace the None with some mapping that correlates with the job. Sort of like how malloc works. I'm not sure if this approach is on the right path or if a more graceful solution exists

Answer (score 0):

Your scheduler knows when you WANT to schedule a job.  When you try to schedule it you check if the resource is in use.  If not, execute.  If it is, put the job into a priority queue for the resource.  Then when a job finishes, you reschedule it, and immediately execute the next one in the queue if a resource freed up.  This executes jobs needing the resource in the order which they tried to be available.

This works for unshared resources.  Shared is a little more complicated.  When you get one you add an entry in the unshared queue for the shared resources, then add the shared one to a bucket.  When the shared entry gets its turn, you start ALL the jobs that can share.  And for a period will immediately start new shared jobs that come along as long as they won't take too long (you have to decide "too long", but not taking this into account leads to resource starvation).  Then you finish the shared, and start doing unshared again until the next time you have a shared period come up.